# wxTreeCtrl custom event

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm struggling with the events for a wxTreeCtrl and can't get them to fire. I want a change select event to fire and have tried to look at the treeCtrl code sample. So far I have:

.cpp

```
TopRightPanel::TopRightPanel(wxWindow *parent, wxSizer* sizer)
: wxTreeCtrl(parent, 0, wxPoint(513, 0), wxSize(512, 384)) //wxPanel(parent, 513, 0, 512, 384)
{
CreateControls(this);;
}



void TopRightPanel::CreateControls(wxTreeCtrl* parent)
{
    rootId = wxTreeItemId();
    rootId = AddRoot("Particle Systems");
    wxTreeItemId root2Id = parent->AppendItem(rootId, "dlisjdslj");



parent->AppendItem(rootId, "Child 1");
}

void TopRightPanel::OnSelChanged(wxTreeEvent& event)
{

}

    #if USE_GENERIC_TREECTRL
    BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(TopRightPanel, wxGenericTreeCtrl)
    #else
    BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(TopRightPanel, wxTreeCtrl)
   #endif

EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED(TopRightPanel_Ctrl, TopRightPanel::OnSelChanged)

END_EVENT_TABLE()

#define TREE_EVENT_HANDLER(name)                                 \
void TopRightPanel::name(wxTreeEvent& event)                        \
{                                                                \
    LogEvent(wxT(#name), event);                                  \
    SetLastItem(wxTreeItemId());                                 \
    event.Skip();                                                \
}

/*TREE_EVENT_HANDLER(OnBeginRDrag)
TREE_EVENT_HANDLER(OnDeleteItem)
TREE_EVENT_HANDLER(OnGetInfo)
TREE_EVENT_HANDLER(OnSetInfo)
TREE_EVENT_HANDLER(OnItemExpanded)
TREE_EVENT_HANDLER(OnItemExpanding)
TREE_EVENT_HANDLER(OnItemCollapsed)*/
//TREE_EVENT_HANDLER(OnSelChanged)
//TREE_EVENT_HANDLER(OnSelChanging)

#undef TREE_EVENT_HANDLER
```

.h

```
class TopRightPanel : public wxTreeCtrl
{
public:
    TopRightPanel(wxWindow *parent, wxSizer *sizer);
    void CreateControls(wxTreeCtrl *parent);
    void CreateNewParent(wxTreeCtrl *parent);
    void CreateNewChild(wxTreeCtrl *parent, wxTreeItemId *root);
    void OnSelChanged(wxTreeEvent& event);
    void LogEvent(const wxChar *name, const wxTreeEvent& event);
    //void OnSelChanging(wxTreeEvent& event);

private:
    wxTreeItemId rootId;
    //DECLARE_DYNAMIC_CLASS(TopRightPanel);
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
    /*void OnSetText(wxCommandEvent & event);
    wxStaticText *m_text;*/

};
enum
{
    TopRightPanel_Select = 6000,
    TopRightPanel_Unselect,
    TopRightPanel_Ctrl = 1000
};
```

If you can see anything I'd really appreciate the advice. I've just been testing so far by trying to place a breakpoint in the OnSelChanged function but it's not hitting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong control ID. You create the TreeCtrl with an ID of `0` while you create an event sink for ID `TopRightPanel_Ctrl`:

```
: wxTreeCtrl(parent, TopRightPanel_Ctrl, ...
//                    ^
//                    | they need to match
//                    v
EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED(TopRightPanel_Ctrl, ...
```